# Regenerative braking circuit for a BLDC Motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, powermosfet

[image]I am trying to design a regenerative braking circuit for clamping the voltage when it is increased due to BLDC Motor acting as a generator. Simulation wise I am getting the exact result. But when I implemented the same circuit the resistor is directly dissipating the heat when power supply is switched on. Actually the power resistor has to be activated when the pulse is generated by the control circuit.

Now my question is why the power resistor is dissipating the energy when I switched on the power supply. Will there be any fault due to the n-channel mosfet which closes the circuit when control circuit initiates the pulse?

N-channel mosfet connections -  Gate receives control signal from p-channel mosfet drain, n-mosfet drain is connected in series to the power resistor one end and the n-mosfet source is connected to ground.

One end of power resistor is connected to the diode cathode and diode anode is connected to variable supply voltage (0-60V).

Comment: Please provide a circuit schematic

Comment: Don't disappear once you've asked a question thinking it's 100% perfect. The lack of a circuit diagram is profoundly problematic. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: *Simulation wise I...* So how hard is it then to make a screenshot of the circuit in the simulator and include it here?

Comment: I have updated the question with detailed circuit , please give your valuable feed back

Comment: A detailed circuit would include op-amp type, mosfets types etc... If you are using a 741 op-amp then the P channel MOSFET will likely never turn off.

Comment: Components use din the above circuit are. Op-Amp LM 324N (IC), p-mosfet : IRF9640, n-mosfet: IRF 530

Comment: Please provide voltage measurements for all relevant circuit nodes (op amp inputs and output, Gate and Drain of both FETs, power supply voltages).